# Is it possible do redirect in development environment from backend to frontend?

Tags: github, redirect, oauth-2.0, localhost, vapor

In my OAuth 2.0 authentication setup, Github will send `code` not to frontend, but to backend.

In prod backend and frontend are under the same domain. Frontend on `/` route, backend on `/api`.

Backend can trigger a redirect. But what to do in development, in local environment?

What if backend runs on `http://127.0.0.1:8080` an frontend on `http://localhost:3000`

Can a Vapor app trigger a redirect if the request was initiated by Github?

Like this:

[image]